# How to set a div containing many images as background?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[This is the motive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8S4u.png)

The background image is not a single file but collection of many thumbnail captured inside a div tag

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Background extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={pictures:[]}
}
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api?results=300')
    .then(results=>{
        return results.json();
    }).then(data=>{
        let pictures=data.results.map((pic)=>{
            return(
                <span key={pic.login.uuid}>
                    <img src={pic.picture.medium} alt=''/>
                </span>
                )
        })
        this.setState({pictures:pictures})
    })
}

render(){
    return(
            <div className="Container1">
            {this.state.pictures}
            </div>
        )
}
}

export default Background;
```

How should my css should be for `Container1` class and for my `app` class which has the main content?

Comment: If the pictures are always the same, why not creating one big picture with all the thumbnails added and set it as the background-image property of your div? Otherwise you would've too many requests slowing down your app.

Comment: @kev no the images are coming from API. Hence can not forsake it will be same all the time. Also, not caring for the performance now in regards with many requests.

Comment: check this once https://github.com/benhowell/react-grid-gallery

Answer (score 1):

The following link would be helpful :
https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-use-multiple-background-images-with-css.cfm

Another solution would be to create a **css flex container** and dynamically create a  element for each image of your `pictures` array.

Check [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) link for more info on flex layout.

Comment: first link is broken :(

Comment: You can find the article via the WayBackMachine at this link https://web.archive.org/web/20220603190659/https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-use-multiple-background-images-with-css/


The CSS suggestion in the article is:
background-image:url(img1.png), url(img2.png), url(img3.png);
background-position:center top, right top, center bottom;
background-repeat:no-repeat, repeat-x, repeat-y;